# How to Vertical Align Center Text in Grid-Layout Bootstrap5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have Bootstrap 5.1.3 and
My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Dòng code dưới để add Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Dòng code dưới để add Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="row" style="height:100px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4 bg-primary">R1 C1 need Vertical align centered</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-danger">R1 C2 need Vertical align centered</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 bg-info">R1 C3 need Vertical align centered</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:79px">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-info">R2 C1 need Vertical align centered</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-danger">R2 C2 need Vertical align centered</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My link Example fiddle: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/aibietlagi/noyjf1hs/3/)

I want to Vertical Center Text in Column with Height:100px... how can do it? thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer, which is the attributes:

> height:100px; line-height:100px;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row text-white text-center" style="height:100px;line-height:100px">
     <div class="col-sm-6 bg-primary">R1 C1 Centered</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 bg-dark">R2 C2 Centered</div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 bg-success">R3 C3 Centered</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The line-height helped me. Thanks for publishing your result.